# Using local js files withing an ejs template

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

So I've been trying to access a local js file within my `ejs` template but I can't figure out on how to do this.
I've tried creating a `public` folder and then add the files in there, and then this :

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

But it keeps saying that the files are not found.
Can someone please explain me how to do this?

The template is nothing special and the rest is a simple `express` setup.
My scripts are in /views/scripts but it seems impossible to access those.

Comment: What you are looking for is app.use(express.static('public'))

Comment: And how do I specify the file then? Just `/scripts/auth.js` for example? @tiborK
EDIT: Found it, thanks !

Comment: Yes. Check out the documentation here https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 0):

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))` //use the following code to serve images,CSS & JS files in a `public` folder.

so the folder structure for `front-end` will be like this...

```
public
      ---js
           ----javascript1.js
           ----javascript2.js
      ---css
           ----css1.js
           ----css2.js
      ---images
           ----img1.js
           ----img2.js
```

change the second script tag to :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/javascript1.js"></script>
```

For more details of  [express.js static-files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)